# Getting -bash: mvn: command not found

Tags: bash, maven-2, macos

I tried setting the Maven PATH in .profile file as well using export commands in terminal(Mac OSX). But, on running mvn commands, getting -bash: mvn: command not found

Please help.

Comment: You need some more clarification here.  Should be an easy fix, but there is no debugging information at all in the question post.

Answer (score 4):

What did you set up exactly? Did you setup PATH like this (or something equivalent):

```
export PATH=$PATH:...:$M2_HOME/bin
```

If yes, did you logout and login again? According to the bash manpage:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive
>   **login shell**, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the `--login` option, it
>   first reads and executes commands from
>   the file `/etc/profile`, if that file
>   exists. After reading that file, it
>   looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable. The `--noprofile` option may
>   be used when the shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.
>   ...
>   When an
>   interactive shell that is **not a login
>   shell** is started, bash reads and
>   executes commands from
>   `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if
>   these files exist. This may be
>   inhibited by using the `--norc` option.
>   The `--rcfile` file option will force
>   bash to read and execute commands from
>   file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and
>   `~/.bashrc`.

As you can see, commands from `.profile` are not executed for a non-login shell (the type of shells you open after logging in). So you have to logout/login or to source the file manually to take your setup into account. See this [blog post](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others) for more details.

Comment: On Mac OS X, the Terminal executes "login -fp $USER" on startup.

Comment: So, you only need to close and reopen the Terminal.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'm not a mac user, I didn't know "normal" shells were login shells on mac. But indeed, closing and reopening a terminal should then do the trick. I'd like to see the output of `echo $PATH` though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Maven, already? If you use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install Maven, you won't need to edit your PATH.