# How to install Maven in Mac Catalina?

Tags: maven, terminal, macos-catalina

I just installed Maven via Mac Catalina via command line  and mvn -version was showing output. then it went away. Please help.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: try what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028872/mvn-command-not-found-in-osx-mavrerick/21030998), the path export part in the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mvn command not found in OSX Mavrerick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028872/mvn-command-not-found-in-osx-mavrerick)

Answer (score 4):

May be a long post, but in the end you will have a convenient tool to install packages and understanding of how to configure them.

Why maven "disappeared" I have no idea of, so what I would do in this situation:
First of all, I would delete maven manually (find the directory and remove it along with any other files that were setup during maven installation)

Then I would highly recommend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_ru) - a package manager for macOS
To install Homebrew, open terminal and execute the following command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Wait for a couple of minutes (a less) until it is installed

Now, that Homebrew is installed, you have a very convenient tool to install stuff on your mac

So, you want to install Maven. You can find [Maven on Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/maven)

Now you just have to open your terminal again and execute

```
brew install maven
```

After a few seconds brew will display the directory it installed Maven in (by default, all Homebrew packages are installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/`)

You are almost there, now you need to set the environment variable.

[As described by Apache](https://maven.apache.org/install.html), the environment variable needs to be added to the `PATH` environment variable.

Here I have some uncertainty in terms of what file to use: `.bash_profile` or `zprofile`. The confusion is caused by the fact that in latest macOS update (maybe several latest updates) Apple decided to use zsh shell, and so `.bash_profile` became somewhat functionally equivalent to `zprofile`. There are many articles on the Internet about what file to use, so you better check them out before proceeding (sorry for not providing links).

On my Catalina 10.15.6 I use `.zprofile` and everything looks to work perfectly.

Once you decide what file to use, execute the following in the terminal:

```
nano .zprofile
```

An editor will open, write this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/*version*/bin:$PATH
```

Press Control + X to exit, then Y to save changes and hit Enter to exit the editor

After that you will again be in terminal, where execute:

```
source .zprofile
```

To load it. Then close the terminal, open again and check that PATH variable is edited by executing:

```
env
```

That's it! Good luck coding!

Comment: I deleted all manually..restarted and then did brew install again..I worked ..thank you

Comment: @ishu Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

**For MacOs Catalina, below is what worked for me.**

Terminal > Vim .zprofile

**Add:**

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/Users/username/apache-maven-3.8.1 (This is where my maven folder is.)
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Terminal > source ~/.bash_profile

Restart Terminal > mvn -version

**Output:**

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /Users/username/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_281, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
username@C02F ~ % java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try executing:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```