# Custom Path in PATH Variable is Not Working on Mac

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, macos-big-sur

**What I am trying to achieve**

I added a custom location in the PATH variable hoping that I could run shell scripts placed in that location easily. But it is not working as I expected.

Here is what `echo $PATH` returns

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/code/lab/pathcommands:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I have placed my script file named `pause` in `$HOME/code/lab/pathcommands` path. I was hoping I could just run `pause` from the terminal and it would run the script file. But it returns
`zsh: command not found: pause`

If I place the same script file in `/usr/local/bin` (which is also a part of $PATH variable), it works as expected.

What am I missing?

My OS - macOS Big Sur

Terminal - iTerm2

Comment: If `echo $PATH` returns the characters `$HOME` and not the _value_ of $HOME, then you've defined your path incorrectly. Show us how you modified your PATH.

Comment: @glennjackman I added `$HOME/code/lab/pathcommands` at the end of `/etc/paths` file.

Comment: When I replaced `$HOME` with actual value. It started working. Thank you @glennjackman.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange issue, after one year of using maven like:

```
export someDir=direct/path/without/other/variables    
export PATH=$PATH:$someDir/maven/bin
```

the system suddenly stopped recognising 'mvn any' command with the message:

> zsh: command not found: mvn

But when I changed my ~/.zprofile so the PATH variable looked like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:direct/path/without/other/variables/maven/bin
```

Everything proceeded to work as expected.